# How to save UIImage view and text within it to disk

Tags: ios, uiview, nsstring, uiimage, png

I have an iOS app that draws shapes on the screen using a UIImage subclassed view and UIBezierPath to draw the lines of the shape.

Here is the code to draw the text:

```
// This is inside a loop
const unsigned int row       = i; 
const unsigned int column    = j;

NSString* rowColumnId = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d, %d", column, row ];
CGPoint textCoord = shapeCoord[0];
textCoord.x += 5;
textCoord.y += 5;

[rowColumnId drawAtPoint:textCoord withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:9.0]];
```

On the screen, everything looks fine; both the shapes and the text are visible in both the iOS simulator and my iOS device

I needed to save the view as a PNG image, so I used the following code to do so:

```
// set up the rendering context
CGSize  boardViewSize = [self bounds].size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(boardViewSize);
[[self layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

// draw the view
UIImage*    viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// convert to PNG
NSData*     pngData  = UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage);
UIImage*    pngImage = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
return pngImage;
```

When I save the PNG, all I see are the shapes.

What code is needed in order to save the NSString drawn text as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured out the problem was that black text does not appear on a transparent PNG, though it is there.

So, the above listed question can be disregarded.